# Unable to copy sheet with VBA Excel under specified name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the Excel sheet under the specified name.

My code looks as follows:

```
Sub GetJoins()

Dim tws As Worksheet, jws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet
Dim shnm As String

Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet")
Set jws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Joint Name")

shnm = tws.Range("B4").Value
Sheets("Joint Name").Copy After:=Sheets("Frontsheet").Name = shnm
nws = jws.Copy(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet"))

End Sub
```

At the following line:

```
  nws = jws.Copy(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet"))
```

I get the following error:
**Expected function or variable**

How could I copy the worksheet under the specified name?

Comment: Several things going wrong here; `Sheet.Copy` doesn't take a Name argument (and it wouldn't have a dot if it did); `Sheet.Copy` also doesn't return a value so you can't assign it to anything. However, it makes the new copy the active sheet, so you can assign a new name to `ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: Also, was it your intention that your code attempts to create two new copies? There are two Copy commands here.

Comment: For the following: ActiveSheet.Name = shnm I am getting: Application defined or object defined error.
Only the fixed name come sthrough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Worksheet After Worksheet

**Basic**

```vb
Sub GetJoins()
  
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim fws As Worksheet: Set fws = wb.Sheets("Frontsheet")
    Dim NewName As String: NewName = CStr(fws.Range("B4").Value)
    
    Dim jws As Worksheet: Set jws = wb.Sheets("Joint Name")
    
    jws.Copy After:=fws
    
    fws.Next.Name = NewName
    ' or:
    'Dim nws As Worksheet: Set nws = fws.Next
    'nws.Name = NewName
    
End Sub
```

**Safer**

```vb
Sub GetJoinsSafer()
  
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim fws As Worksheet: Set fws = wb.Sheets("Frontsheet")
    Dim NewName As String: NewName = CStr(fws.Range("B4").Value)
    
    Dim nsh As Object:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set nsh = wb.Sheets(NewName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not nsh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "A sheet named """ & nsh.Name & """ already exists!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim jws As Worksheet: Set jws = wb.Sheets("Joint Name")
    
    jws.Copy After:=fws
    fws.Next.Name = NewName
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The last line catches an error: Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Sure, if you're trying to use an empty string as a name.

Comment: Right I see.... Thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

The Copy function gives back a Boolean value of the success of the function.

Since the copied sheet will be the activesheet, to name the copied sheet this is a workaround

```
shnm = tws.Range("B4").Value
Sheets("Joint Name").Copy After:=Sheets("Frontsheet")
Activesheet.Name = shnm
nws = jws.Copy(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet"))
```

I just now observed that nws is a worksheet object. As i mentioned above the return value is a Boolean type. This you cannot assign to a Worksheet object. Delete the  declaration of `nws`.

Comment: Expected function or variable - it keep showing me this error all the time.

Comment: @geographos Added the explanation to the answer

Comment: Yes, now it's working. Thank you so much!